# Misplaced Bracket in C

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include<ctype.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);
int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner
    if ( score1 > score2)
    printf ("Player 1 Wins!");

    if ( score1 < score2)
    printf("Player 2 Wins!");

    if ( score1 ==  score2)
    printf("Tie!");


 int compute_score(string word)
    **{**


    for (int i=0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        if (isupper(word[i]))
    }
    int score=0
{
    score = score + POINTS[word[i] - 65];
}

if   (islower(word[i]))
{
 score = score + POINTS[word[i] - 97];
 return score;
}
}
}
```

The bolded bracket is where the code is pointing towards. I am not sure what the solution is. I am using C and this is my CS50 assignment. This is the error message:

```
scrabble.c:32:5: error: function definition is not allowed here
    {
    ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: scrabble] Error 1
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a ```}``` before ```int compute_score(string word)``` to end the previous function?   Or at least move that last ```}``` to before ```int compute_score...```.

Comment: C doesn't allow function definitions to be nested in `main()`. Close `main()` before your define your function...

Comment: Delete one of the three closing brackets at the bottom, and add a closing bracket after `printf("Tie!");`. The implementation of the function `compute_score` is misplaced within the body of `main`. Also, consider using a code formatter to automatically format the code, which allows you to spot the problem faster.

Comment: I see what you are saying, I tried to close the bracket but the error message is still the same. Do you know how I can get a code formatter?

Comment: If you are using an IDE to do the development, most IDE's should come with code formatting features, in which case you should consult the documentation of your IDE. If you are using text editors and command-line tools, you may take a look at tools like `clang-format`.

Comment: if you use three backquotes you can add code without the need to indent it four spaces.  I tried to reformat your code, but as it has many syntactic errors and is not compilable, I preferred to vote to close the question and allow you to edit it in a proper manner.  Read the help in order to know how to format the code to be used in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of `'}'` and `'{'` braces mixed around and you have a stray `return score;` in the wrong location. Based on my read of your code, you are looking for:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 
                1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // Print the winner
    if ( score1 > score2)
        puts ("Player 1 Wins!");

    if ( score1 < score2)
        puts ("Player 2 Wins!");

    if ( score1 ==  score2)
        puts ("Tie!");
}

int compute_score (string word)
{
    int score = 0;
    
    for (int i=0; word[i]; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(word[i]))
        {
            score = score + POINTS[word[i] - 65];
        }
    
        if (islower(word[i]))
        {
            score = score + POINTS[word[i] - 97];
        }

    }
    
    return score;
}
```

(**note:** properly formatting, indenting and spacing your code can make errors easier to spot)

Be consistent in your use of braces to guard blocks of code. For instance you use no guard in:

```c
    if ( score1 > score2)
        printf ("Player 1 Wins!");
```

but then guard each `if` in:

```c
        if (isupper(word[i]))
        {
            score = score + POINTS[word[i] - 65];
        }
```

I would encourage you to guard every block. That way your code with have a consistent look -- and avoid the stray unguarded command you intended to include in a block but missed.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, but when trying to execute your code I get a Segmentation Fault. When player 1 and 2 input their word, instead of printing "Player 1 Wins" or "Player 2 Wins" it says segmentation fault. Do you know a solution to this error?

Comment: Oh, if you want me to look at the rest I will, hold on. (sorry had `word[1]` instead of `word[i]` - happens when you get old...)

Comment: Oh ok, that was the solution. Thank you, David!

Comment: Ah, the problems of aging... Overlooking the magic numbers 65 & 97 and not having the energy to chide the OP with a better way known to us oldies... `:-)` Keep on truckin'... `:-)`